# I have changed the CompileSdkVersion from 25 to 29 while I am using RecyclerView support lib but there is no version 29 available

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In an Android application,

I have changed the CompileSdkVersion from **25** to **29** while I am using RecyclerView support lib as following:

> implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

Now on Sync Gradle, I see the following error:

> The suport library should not use a different version

The problem is when I look for recyclerview-v7:2**9**, there is no version 29 available (the latest version is 28)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

remove the dependency implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

remove the recyclerView that you used.

then try to add a new RecyclerView that will promt you to automatically implement dependency